# My python play again feature does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def playAgain():
    while True:
        try:
            replay = input("Do you want to play again? ").lower() #Asking user to play again
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, Invalid Entry") #If response invalid, will ask again
            continue
        if replay in ("yes","y","true","t"):
            main()
        elif replay in ("no","n","false","f"):
            print ("Goodbye")
            return
        else: #If input is invalid will ask again
            print("Invalid entry, Please enter yes or no")

def main():
    print ("Hello")
    playAgain()

main()
```

For my homework, I am required to make a quiz. I have got it all to work accept for the play again feature which you can see above. I am having trouble exiting the program. If I type in no the first time it asks me do you want to play again it will exit correctly. The problem I have is if I type in yes the first time and then `no` the second time, it will not exit. The program will ask me the question again a third time where if I press no it will exit correctly.

I know the solution is probably very obvious but I can't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `main` calls `playAgain`. Then, if you select to play again, `playAgain` calls `main` recursively.

```
 main -> playAgain -> main -> playAgain
                                 ^^^
```

If you `return` here, only the second `playAgain` exits, then the program goes back to the main loop in the first `playAgain`.

To fix it, add `return` to exit the main loop when the user selects to play again as well:

```
    if replay in ("yes","y","true","t"):
        main()
        return   # here
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Python 2.7`:

```
def playAgain():
    while True:
        try:
            replay = raw_input("Do you want to play again? ").lower() #Asking user to play again
            if replay in ("yes","y","true","t"):
                main()
                return
            elif replay in ("no","n","false","f"):
                print ("Goodbye")
                return
            else: #If input is invalid will ask again
                print("Invalid entry, Please enter yes or no")
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, Invalid Entry") #If response invalid, will ask again

def main():
    print ("Hello")
    playAgain()

main()
```